# Proving something is a convolution operator...

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory

If we define the operator 
$K(a)=F^{−1}aF$

where $ F:L^2({\mathbb R})\to L^2({\mathbb R})$, is the fourier transform given by 
$$\left(Ff\right)\left(x\right)=\int_{{\mathbb R}}{f\left(t\right)e^{itx}dt,\ \ \ \ x\in {\mathbb R}}.$$ and $a$  is a function on $L^{\infty}$, which makes the operator K map the dense subset $L^2({\mathbb R})\cap L^p({\mathbb R}),$ of $L^p({\mathbb R}),$ onto itself and extends to a bounded linear operator on $L^p({\mathbb R})$.

Any idea on how to prove (or how to see) that K is a convolution operator?

Comment: $\widehat{f*g}=\hat{f}\hat{g}$

Comment: What have you tried?  Certainly it would be handy if $a = F^{-1}Fa$ and then apply the idea of @mathematician would be a place to start...